# Pagination on scroll in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following UICollectionViewLayout for my UICollectionView.

```
class CustomCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout { 

var numberOfColumns = 8
var itemAttributes : NSMutableArray!
var itemsSize : NSMutableArray!
var contentSize : CGSize!

override func prepareLayout() {

    if self.collectionView?.numberOfSections() == 0 {
        return
    }

    if (self.itemAttributes != nil && self.itemAttributes.count > 0) {
        for section in 0..<self.collectionView!.numberOfSections() {
            var numberOfItems : Int = self.collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section)
            for index in 0..<numberOfItems {
                if section != 0 && index != 0 {
                    continue
                }

                var attributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: section))
                if section == 0 {
                    var frame = attributes.frame
                    frame.origin.y = self.collectionView!.contentOffset.y
                    attributes.frame = frame
                }

                if index == 0 {
                    var frame = attributes.frame
                    frame.origin.x = self.collectionView!.contentOffset.x
                    attributes.frame = frame
                }
            }
        }
        return
    }

    if (self.itemsSize == nil || self.itemsSize.count != numberOfColumns) {
        self.calculateItemsSize()
    }

    var column = 0
    var xOffset : CGFloat = 0
    var yOffset : CGFloat = 0
    var contentWidth : CGFloat = 0
    var contentHeight : CGFloat = 0

    for section in 0..<self.collectionView!.numberOfSections() {
        var sectionAttributes = NSMutableArray()

        for index in 0..<numberOfColumns {
            var itemSize = self.itemsSize[index].CGSizeValue()
            var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: section)
            var attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)
            attributes.frame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, itemSize.width, itemSize.height+20))

            if section == 0 && index == 0 {
                attributes.zIndex = 1024;
            } else  if section == 0 || index == 0 {
                attributes.zIndex = 1023
            }

            if section == 0 {
                var frame = attributes.frame
                frame.origin.y = self.collectionView!.contentOffset.y
                attributes.frame = frame
            }
            if index == 0 {
                var frame = attributes.frame
                frame.origin.x = self.collectionView!.contentOffset.x
                attributes.frame = frame
            }

            sectionAttributes.addObject(attributes)

            xOffset += itemSize.width
            column++

            if column == numberOfColumns {
                if xOffset > contentWidth {
                    contentWidth = xOffset
                }

                column = 0
                xOffset = 0
                yOffset += itemSize.height+20
            }
        }
        if (self.itemAttributes == nil) {
            self.itemAttributes = NSMutableArray(capacity: self.collectionView!.numberOfSections())
        }
        self.itemAttributes .addObject(sectionAttributes)
    }

    var attributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = self.itemAttributes.lastObject?.lastObject as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
    contentHeight = attributes.frame.origin.y + attributes.frame.size.height
    self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth+150, contentHeight)
}

override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
    return self.contentSize
}

override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! {

    let BondData:NSArray = self.itemAttributes[indexPath.section] as! NSArray

    return BondData[indexPath.row] as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

}

override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    if self.itemAttributes != nil {
        for section in self.itemAttributes {

            let filteredArray  =  section.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(

                NSPredicate(block: { (evaluatedObject, bindings) -> Bool in
                    return CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, evaluatedObject!.frame)
                })
                ) as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]

            attributes.appendContentsOf(filteredArray)
        }
    }

    return attributes
}

override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func sizeForItemWithColumnIndex(columnIndex: Int) -> CGSize {
    var text : String = ""
    switch (columnIndex) {
    case 0:
        text = "Col 0"
    case 1:
        text = "Col 1"
    case 2:
        text = "Col 2"
    case 3:
        text = "Col 3"
    case 4:
        text = "Col 4"
    case 5:
        text = "Col 5"
    case 6:
        text = "Col 6"
    case 7:
        text = "Col 7"        
    default:
        text = "Col 8"
    }

    let size : CGSize = (text as NSString).sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17.0)])
    let width : CGFloat = size.width + 80
    return CGSizeMake(width, 30)
}

func calculateItemsSize() {

    self.itemsSize = NSMutableArray(capacity: numberOfColumns)
    for index in 0..<numberOfColumns {
        self.itemsSize.addObject(NSValue(CGSize: self.sizeForItemWithColumnIndex(index)))
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement pagination on scroll in UICollectionView using following code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {          
            let seconds = 7.0
            let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

            dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                self.loadMore()

                self.DataTableCollectionView.reloadData()                   

            })
```

}

But in doing so by using above code I am getting an error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 50 beyond bounds [0 .. 49]'"

I am using following code to create table using UICollectionView
https://github.com/brightec/CustomCollectionViewLayout

How can I get this right? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The problem lies in the fact that you are trying to access an array beyond its index. It's not really relevant to the title of the question.
2. You should provide and set the properties of the cell in `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`, not reload data and the like.